# Promise inside a loop inside an async function

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project using react and firebase and redux and I have some items that did created by a user. I'm storing the id of the user in the item object so i can populate the user later when i get the item to display.

Now I'm trying to get the items and modify them by replacing the user id with the actual info about the user but I have a promises problem. In my code I just get an empty array which mean the modification didn't get resolved before I return the final result.

```
export const getItems = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firestore = getFirebase().firestore();
    const items = [];
    const dbRef = firestore.collection('items').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(2);

    return dbRef
      .get()
      .then((res) => {
        const firstVisible = res.docs[0];
        const lastVisible = res.docs[res.docs.length - 1];

        async function getData(res) {

/////////////////////////////////////////////// how to finish this code befor jumping to the return line
          await res.forEach((doc) => {
            firestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(doc.data().owner)
              .get()
              .then((res) => {
                items.push({ ...doc.data(), owner: res.data() });
              });
          });
////////////////////////////////////////////////

          return { docs: items, lastVisible, firstVisible };
        }

        return getData(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: First of all. My suggestion is use for in or for of to use a loop of promises. My second is or use try and catch or use  then and catch. When you are using a async and await I should just use try catch instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get exactly what you are trying to do, but I would suggest putting some order to make your code easy to read and work with.

You can use `for of` to manage async looping. I suggest something like this, disclaimer, I did it at the eye, problably there are some errors, but you can get the idea.

```
const getAllDocs = function (data) {
    let temp = [];
    data.forEach(function (doc) {
        temp.push(doc.data());
    });
    return { data: temp };
};

const getDoc = snap => (snap.exists ? { data: snap.data() } : {});

export const getItems = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
        const firestore = getFirebase().firestore();
        const dbRef = firestore.collection('items').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(2);
        const usersRef = firestore.collection('users');
        let temps = [];

        const { data: items } = await dbRef.get().then(getAllDocs);
        const firstVisible = items[0];
        const lastVisible = items[items.length - 1];

        for (const item of items) {
            const { data: user } = await usersRef.doc(item.owner).get().then(getDoc);
            const owner = {
                /* whatever this means*/
            };
            temps.push({ ...user, owner });
        }

        return { docs: temps, lastVisible, firstVisible };    
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot  man that did solve the problem and now i know i need to practice promises to get better handling them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an array of Promises is not itself a Promise -- so `await`ing it will be a no-op.

You can solve this using `Promise.all` if you want to load them all asynchronously.

```js
const items = await Promise.all(res.map(async (doc) => {
  const res = await firestore.collection('users').doc(doc.data().owner).get();
  return { ...doc.data(), owner: res.data() };
});
```

Otherwise you can `await` in a for loop as suggested in other answers.